# How to check access of the model creator in Controller in yii?

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I don't know the best approach for access rules of the creator of model in the controller. I usually using like this :

```
public function accessRules() {
    return array(
       ...

        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions' => array('docrop', 'cropimages','upload','setting','updateprivacy','updateuser','changepassword'),
            'expression' => array($this,'isCreator'),
        ),
       ... 

    );
}
```

And then in that controller I'm using this function to check the correct access rules

```
 public function isCreator(){
    $hasil=false;
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $idUser=$_GET['id'];
        $hasil=$idUser==Yii::app()->user->id?true:false;
    }
    return $hasil;
 }
```

And then If I want to create the url I always use the id parameter in that url. Is this the best approach? Or there is an alternative ways that better than this?

Comment: You can use RBAC. Check http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#role-based-access-control

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach would allow users to change the id in the url, giving them access to all actions. If you **really** would like to keep this method, I suggest using some kind of hashing method to make it less brute-forceable in combination with e.g. his ip address for more security: `$hashFromUrl == md5(Yii::app()->user->id . CHttpRequest::getUserHostAddress())`. Nonetheless I discourage this approach.

As the method is called `isCreator()`, I assume that you want to check whether the current user is the creator/author of an existing model in the database. Can't you use a `creatorId` field for this model to compare against the current user's id? No client side hacks are required then.